# Select last row in chat conversation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
+---+--------+----------+---------+
|id | sender | receiver | created |
+---+--------+----------+---------+
  1     4         9       3333
  2     9         4       3334
  3     4         9       3335
  4     5         4       3336
  5     4         9       3337
```

My query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM chat_messages 
WHERE sender = 4 OR receiver = 4
GROUP BY sender, receiver
ORDER BY created DESC
```

The result is:

```
+---+--------+----------+---------+
|id | sender | receiver | created |
+---+--------+----------+---------+
  5     4         9       3337
  4     5         4       3336
  2     9         4       3334
```

I am closer to what I look for. I am looking for this result:

```
+---+--------+----------+---------+
|id | sender | receiver | created |
+---+--------+----------+---------+
  5     4         9       3337
  4     5         4       3336
```

Meaning, I want the latest row if the conversation is of the user `n`, and other rows where the user `n` is a `sender` or a `receiver`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the description, it seems like you want all rows !?!

Comment: Yes, where the user `n` is involved (either as sender or receiver)

Comment: But that's not what you indicated in your result set

Comment: It does I think. In my result set I have all rows that belongs to the user `n`,  only the last event of the conversation. The user `4` has conversation with `9` and `5`, I have the last event with `9` and the only event with `5`

Comment: Perhaps we interpret 'and other rows' differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filtering in the `where` clause.  Here is one method:

```
select cm.*
from chat_messages cm
where cm.created = (select max(cm2.created)
                    from chat_messages cm2
                    where (cm2.sender, cm2.receiver) in ( (cm.sender, cm.receiver), (cm.receiver, cm.sender))
                   ) and
      4 in (cm.receiver, cm.sender);
```

If you just want the created time and id, you might find that aggregation works better:

```
select least(cm.receiver, cm.sender),
       greatest(cm.receiver, cm.sender),
       max(cm.id), max(cm.created)
from chat_message cm
where 4 in (cm.receiver, cm.sender)
group by least(cm.receiver, cm.sender), greatest(cm.receiver, cm.sender);
```